# Best way to sign-up django project

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a project about a workshop where you could sign up for it. When you sign up for an project, and you click on the project to go to the detailview you wil see a list of all the people that are currently signed up for that workshop. i dont know a way to make that sign up function. Do you have some idea how to do this?

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: I made a signup model that has a foreignkey relation to workshop. The signup model has an empty Integerfield. My idea was to take the users pk and add it to an hidden input field. Submit this field get the post, save it to the model and then to display the users just use their pk.

Comment: can you paste your code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to first try the example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/).

If you do not have the patience to read through the documentation, here is an example of [something you can try](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/login.html).